# What's the difference between gen_server and gen_statem?

Tags: erlang, gen-server, gen-statem

In Erlang there are two behaviors that seem to be pretty similar:

```erlang
-behaviour(gen_server).
-behaviour(gen_statem).
```

What is the practical difference? When should I use one over another?

Comment: *What is the practical difference?* -- Most people will never be able to figure out how to use gen_statem or comprehend what a finite state machine is used for.

Answer (score 3):

`gen_server` stands for "generic server", and it's a framework/interface to build processes that handle requests and events.

`gen_statem` stands for "generic state machine" and it's a framework/interface to build processes that behave as state machines reacting to events.

You could build a state machine on top of a `gen_server` or have a single-state state machine acting as a server.

To choose between one and the other you should check the relevant chapter in the [doc](https://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/statem.html#when-to-use-gen_statem), but I'd narrow it down to:

If you need to model a state machine, consider the features provided by `gen_statem`. For simple state machines without bells and whistles `gen_server` works fine and it's simpler.